# Laptop WiFi is not working from reasonable distance

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop

I have a ASUS [n551JX](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/N551JX/). The router is in main level (middle floor). We can connect all our mobile phones from all corners of my house except this Asus laptop. Well, it gets connected after trying for several times, but then starts dropping packets. Around 70% packet loss on average.

For last few months I have been noticing this problem happens when working from other floor but working from same floor used to work. But for last few days situation is even worse, it is only working if I sit right beside my router. So something is definitely wrong with the Wifi card.

- Have any experienced this before?
- Do I need to replace the wifi card?
- or the Wifi card might have gotten loose?

[NIC Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uv4DQ.png) added as requested in comments show a Qualcomm Atheros AR946x WiFi adapter.

Comment: Has this occurred since first using laptop or did it just happen one day?  If it's the former, it's likely router settings [more likely], or or WiFi driver/driver settings related, but if it's the latter, it's more likely to be a router firmware update, WiFi driver update, or other change.  Have you used Wireshark yet on the laptop to analyze wifi traffic and wireless signals in the house?  Your router's 5GHz channel should be set to one of the highest available _(if in the US, channel 157 generally works the best)_  and the WiFi driver settings should be set to prefer 5GHz AC.

Comment: The card may just be a consumer level card and not capable of much. Unlikely it is loose but it is possible if the card was not screwed down like my machine. You can add a good access point where you need it but best to connect that by Ethernet to your main network point.

Comment: @JW0914 As I said it started occuring gradually. Previously it used work when laptop is within around 10  to 15 feets of router but the laptop needs to be too close to router to work. I did not check wireshark. What would this reveal? My laptop can only work with 2GHz unfortunately.

Comment: @John I have been using this laptop for more than 3 years now. It used to work quite nice but started showing issues for last one year. For last few days its the worst.

Comment: Perhaps replace the card if you think the machine is worth investing in.

Comment: @Samiron According to the ASUS n551X [product page](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/N551VW/specifications/), it only comes in a single configuration for WiFI, an integrated AC card and AC is only supported on 5GHz... unless you meant to say your router only supports 2.4GHz?  It's rare for a WiFi card to fail, and yours appears to be integrated, not modular, and if it was failing, it's radios simply wouldn't work.  It's an almost certainty your issue is router wifi setting or firmware related, or WiFi card settings or driver related... of which requires troubleshooting not possible on Superuser

Comment: @JW0914 That web page you found specifies _Integrated 802.11 a/b/g/n/ac or 802.11 ac (WiDi)_ which means it could run on 2.4GHz _or_ 5GHz frequencies.

Comment: Sorry its https://www.asus.com/Laptops/N551JX/ I will update OP

Comment: @K7AAY It does say it has `Integrated 802.11 b/g/n or 802.11 a/b/g/n` basically means there is no chance of replacing it.

Comment: @Samiron Please also open a Command Prompt and run `wmic nic get AdapterType, AdapterTypeID, DeviceID, Manufacturer, Name, Installed, Speed` then select the result and copy it. Once you have that info, please click [edit] and update your question with it. The manual shows the WiFi is on a _removable, replaceable_ card, and since it sounds like a bad connection issue, I've put instructions to fix that below.

Comment: @K7AAY added a screen of what you are asking

Comment: @Samiron AARRGH Screens are eeevil. Copying text and then pasting it into the question is gooood.

Answer (score 2):

Page 99 of the [manual](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/N551JW/0409_E9396_B.pdf) shows the location of [your WiFi card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mckxn.png) and the two preceding pages show how to get at it. Please open up your laptop following those instructions, remove and re-seat that WiFi card. Also remove the left snap-on antenna wire and reconnect it, then remove and reconnect the right snap-on antenna wire. Then close up the PC and retest your WiFi.

Comment: @Samiron If the WiFi card is mounted in a strange way, just do the unplug/replug of the antennae leads, take a picture of the WiFi card and its mounting, post it to imgur.com or another public posting site, and post the URL to the PIC so I can advise.

Comment: Sure. I will do that as soon as I can

Comment: If reseating the device and antenna does not work, a USB WiFi adapter can be had for <$US8. One with an external antenna *might* give more range, but I've put an adapter at the end of a USB extension cable, added a suction cup, and could move it for greatly improved signal.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot "And if that doesn't work, guys, bang the rocks together."  https://imgur.com/a/uyFVqON

Comment: By antenna you mean these two right? https://imgur.com/u1VjjOw

Comment: @Samiron You've got it right. Those normally terminate in copper-crimp-on contacts. If they are soldered on to the WiFi card, STOP; the card is not removable without a tech to do it.

Comment: Sorry its taking some time. We somehow managed to continue using our laptop setting up a table beside the router. But I will spend some time on this soon.